# RuntimeBinderException in the CSASPNETWebsite sample solution of Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I just started the CSASPNETWebsite website which is a sample example site uses the c# sdk and the dynamic keyword

The main page contain the following code:

```
    var fb = new FacebookClient(this.CurrentSession.AccessToken);
    dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("me");
    lblName.Text = myInfo.name;
```

I got the following exception: 
'Facebook.JsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'name'

from

```
    myInfo.name;
```

(or myInfo.id or anything else that should be)
the type of myInfo at runtime is Facebook.JsonObject, is it should be anything else?
I have added references to Facebook.dll, Facebook.Web.dll and Facebook.Web.Mvc.dll

Thanks in advance,
Alon.

Answer (score 1):

Find my mistake:

The references I add were for DLLs in the .net35 folder (which not contain all the dynamic keyword) instead of the SDK instead of the .net4 folder.

problem solved.